# Undefined variable $total5 to calculate the sum of a column

Tags: undefined

To calculate the sum of a column

here is the code snippet

```
if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event'])){
                $total1= 1;
                if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event2'])){
                    $total2 = 1;
                    //$total1 = $total1 + $total2;
                    if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event3'])){
                        $total3 = 1;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }else{
                        $total3 = 0;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }
                }else{
                    $total2 = 0;
                    //$total1 = $total1 + $total2;
                    if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event3'])){
                        $total3 = 1;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }else{
                        $total3 = 0;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $total1= 0;
                if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event2'])){
                    $total2 = 1;
                    //$total1 = $total1 + $total2;
                    if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event3'])){
                        $total3 = 1;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }else{
                        $total3 = 0;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }
                }else{
                    $total2 = 0;
                    //$total1 = $total1 + $total2;
                    if(!empty($row_Recordset3['event3'])){
                        $total3 = 1;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }else{
                        $total3 = 0;
                        $total1 = $total1 + $total2 + $total3;
                    }

                }

            }

            $total4 = $total1 * 10;
            $total5 += $total4;
```

still new at this please modify if the code is not efficient

The output is correct but there is an error stating that the variable $total5 is undefined.

Is there a way? Thanks

Comment: which programming language ???

Comment: Can you show more of your code?  Where do you initialized the value for $total5 ?